# Tools to test surface control mechanics by computer

Tags: game-design

I'm currently working on designing a board game involving capturing and controlling points on a surface and was wondering if there are ways to test my rules in an application. I've been playing many rounds and it seems to do what I want it to do but I'd like to put 2 computers at it against each other and see if one manages to win.

There seems to be such tools for deck building games as outlined here:
[What is a quick way to test or simulate card strategies for deck building games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/what-is-a-quick-way-to-test-or-simulate-card-strategies-for-deck-building-games)

So my guess is maybe there are other similar tools for testing surface control, like something that could be populated with the rules of chess or checkers for example. Does this exist?

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for a program that will have two computer players play your custom board game against each other, with no interaction or input from you?

Comment: @Malco Yes, I'm aware this might sound crazy though I can currently describe the mechanics with very few simple rules. Again, a bit like checkers and chess. I currently use a hex grid.

Comment: While I don't have the coding proficiency to make such a program, I've seen  Python used in the development of several games. It can be very useful for simulating an arbitrary number of games. (e.g. my co-designer on one current project simulated 10,000 hands of our card game in 5 seconds!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this exists. The best board game implementation tools you can get currently are tabletop simulator and tabletopia and both shy far away from implementing the actual rules.

I'm currently designing a board game myself and am in multiple communities regarding board game design and no one has ever brought anything like that up. I've seen a lot of tools being mentioned, from the directly usefull like card generators or the aforementioned TTS/tabletopia to more meta things like anydice, but I've never seen someone mention a board game AI simulation tool.

The closest thing you might get is VASSAL which is a free open source game engine, but that has ZERO AI support as of now (but being open source, that could be changed by you).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. I'd seen VASSAL shortly after my post but couldn't figure out how I could use it for my situation. I'm not a coder by any means so if someone wants to pick up the idea and run with it, be my guest! (and let me know when you're done)