# What's the best Dominion expansion for beating big money-style strategies?

Tags: dominion

I'm a decently experienced Dominion player (I have the Base set, Intrigue, Seaside, Prosperity and Hinterlands is on it's way) and I'm wondering what would be a good next expansion for beating big-money style strategies?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Pretty much any single action card beats big money ultimate.

Comment: Appears to be half duplicate of ["How can I beat "Big Money" in Dominion?"](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/681/1926), and half [list/recommendation question](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/656/1926).  Voting to close.