# What are good strategies involving Remodel?

Tags: dominion

A basic strategy of using Remodel to upgrade Estates to Remodels, Remodels to Gold, and using Gold to buy or upgrade to Provinces is a powerful but slow strategy, so I haven't been able to win with it.

Are there circumstances in which you would use a Remodel-heavy strategy?  Assume there are no Curses.  How would it work?

[image]

Comment: I've never found Remodel to be very helpful, but apparently there are strategies for it. I'm gonna have to try it some time...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Be Ruthless!

This is basically an extension of the strategy of trashing all your lame cards presented [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/381/what-are-good-standard-tactics-for-dominion). Don't limit yourself to only remodeling Coppers and Remodels. Be ruthless about it: if you get a Remodel in your hand, play it, even if it means passing up other actions, and even if it means you won't get to buy anything. This will keep your deck small and powerful. And, as Powerlord pointed out, this applies to Expand as well, and I'd throw [Upgrade](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=upgrade) into the same box. If [Workshop](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=workshop) happens to be around, it can speed up the process.

[image: Upgrade: Cost: 5 --- +1 Card, +1 Action. Trash a card from your hand. Gain a card costing exactly 1 coin more than it.][image: Workshop: Cost: 3 --- Gain a card costing up to 4 coins.]

Comment: I agree; the key is to Remodel SOMETHING every time you draw it, and to buy more Remodels so you're drawing one every time.  In the initial set, I like to Remodel my Estates into Markets, letting me draw more Remodels.

Comment: You can't remodel estates into Markets - the cost difference is too big...

Comment: This sounds right to me.  When I was trying out the Remodel strategy in the base set, I don't think I was being ruthless enough.

Comment: There has been a new Remodel like card in every set except Alchemy.  Prosperity has Expand ($7), reads identically to Remodel except says $3 instead of $2.  Cornucopia has Remake ($4), which reads similarly to Upgrade but without the +1 Card and +1 Action... but it also says "Do this twice."  The best part of Upgrade and Remake is that you can't get a card back if you trash Curse or a Copper, as the cards you get back have to cost exactly $1 more.

Comment: Having said that, Prosperity also has Forge, where you trash multiple cards and gain a card costing the exact combined cost of the cards you trashed combined.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, heavy use of Remodel works best in conjunction with another strategy; you can't usually rely on it exclusively, but it can give you a strong boost.  Get into the Remodel game early and aggressively (especially when no other trashing options exist).  Most importantly, learn to recognize when other strategies are more powerful than Remodel, and don't be afraid to only buy one and use it only moderately when that's the case.

Remodeling from Coppers and Estates all the way up to Provinces takes a long time, so find a way to buy or gain a lot of Golds through other means, and then use Remodel to bump them to Provinces.  Near the end game, you can be especially aggressive with dumping your Golds, even when it drops your coin in hand down and limits your purchase to a Duchy.

It's also beneficial to combine it with attacks to slow your opponents down enough to let your Remodel strategy come to fruition.

Answer (score 7):

Remodel has 2 major uses, both of which apply games of all very strong players.

1: in the early game, if there are no other better cards to take on turns 1/2 like baron/militia/smithy, then remodel can be a great pick because it let's you trash those estates.

2: in the late game, remodel is used on gold's and nobles to get provinces.  This will very often swing the game if your opponents do not take remodel at the correct time, and you do.

Answer (score 7):

Remodel is especially useful in games without +Buy, allowing you to make an end-game Victory point purchase as well as a remodel.  This can often swing close games to your favor.  I'm a big fan of incorporating Remodel into my strategy and I buy them (and cards like it) early and often.  Great card!!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're discounting Curses here, but...

Remodel can be used to turn a Copper/Curse into any 2-cost card.  If you played a Bridge first, you can turn a Copper/Curse into any 3-cost card (because they now cost 2, and a card's cost cannot go below 0).

Remodel can also be used regain cards lost to Saboteur or Swindler.

The strategies presented here also apply to the Prosperity card Expand, but for 3 more.

[image: Expand]

Comment: Discounting curses because that's a pretty obvious reason to get remodel.

Comment: Hmm, really? I'd say several other trashing cards would be rather better than Remodel for the purposes of dealing with Curses. Having to gain a 2-cost card is not usually a good thing, unless the set includes Pawn or Lighthouse. I think Remodel is an excellent card, but I don't like having to use it at the low end of the chain: I much prefer Remodelling an Estate or a Remodel.

Comment: @AlexC: Believe it or not, there are other 2-cost cards that are useful.  In fact, it's surprising at how many non-terminal two cost cards there are, particularly from Seaside.

Comment: @Alex, agreed in general.  Keep in mind, however, that curses are often present in lengthy and low-scoring games.  Remodeling curses (to estates, even) might make a lot of difference.  If you have cards like Baron and Scout, remodeling into estates might actually be useful as well as get you two VPs.

Answer (score 4):

Remodel is great for turning Gold (3 Treasure, Cost 6) into Provinces (6 VPs, Cost 8,) which can quickly get you tons of points and force a game end. This works especially well with [Mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYaCH.jpg) (which is in the "basic" set of cards,) [Adventurer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiMnx.jpg), and any card(s) which give +2 actions.

- Play your +2 actions card(s)
- If needed, use Adventurer to get Treasure cards (hopefully Copper/Silver) into your hand
- Use Mine(s) to upgrade treasure cards
- Remodel Gold -> Province

You will also have lots of Gold in your hand following this strategy, so it may be possible to simply buy Provinces outright.

This build can also be done without Adventurer, but you will want to build a small deck focusing on treasure, +card cards, and +action cards.

Comment: P.S. Since I am new I cannot embed images or have more than 2 hyperlinks. If you have mod powers feel free to improve my answer's formatting.

Answer (score -1):

1) Remodel the Remodel Card for Gold (4+6)
2) Buy another Remodel during the buy phase to replace the trashed Remodel
3) precisely depending on the speed of the current game, shift your focus from Gold to Provinces, remodeling gold to provinces for the victory!

Comment: "Are there circumstances in which you would use a Remodel-heavy strategy?"